# How to display source code with indent in a web page? HTML? CSS?

Tags: html, css, winforms, browser

I want to show some source code with the WebBrowser control on a winform. And I want to decorate the source code with HTML tags, such as color, font, and size. But I found it difficult to display the **indent** properly.

To be precise, my source code are held in String[], and each String holds the proper indent (space or tab) already. But it seems these kinds of indent are just **ignored** by the WebBrowser control.

Could someone tell me how to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`<pre>` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4) (using [`<code>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1) with appropriate class names to mark up the parts you want to syntax highlight)

```
<pre><code class="javascript"><code class="keyword">function</code> <code class="name">foo</code>()…
```

Answer (score 12):

I like to paste my code in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and then display it that way. Github will recognize the code and format it accordingly.

If you're going to be doing it often you could try [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Or use a one-off formatter like [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into this JavaScript library to highlight and format your code. http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Or you can check out a service like this - http://pygments.appspot.com/ or this - http://hilite.me/