# How to display source code "prettily" in android app

Tags: android, xml

everyone.

## [What I'd like to do]

To display source code "prettily" in android app. Like this.
[image]
At least if there are indents, it's fine.

## [Why?]

Because I'm developing an android app where users can see Views and its source code at the same time.

## [Issue]

Showing source codes on TextView looks ugly. A lot of escape characters needed for <> and the text layout collapsed. Googling and searching on Stackoverflow didn't give me any useful information.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**(update 2015/11/23)**
These link might be useful when you use WebView to display source codes.
- [How can I display HTML source code within a HTML website? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239808/how-can-i-display-html-source-code-within-a-html-website?lq=1)
- [How to display source code with indent in a web page? HTML? CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800723/how-to-display-source-code-with-indent-in-a-web-page-html-css)

Comment: Do you have html content of your code with all these properties set? If yes, why not show them in webView?

Comment: WebView! I should have come up with it. Thanks. But I still have to escape characters... other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the text in a `WebView` is a great idea as you can now use javascript APIs like [Google's Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)
I believe SO uses it ;)

> The comments in prettify.js are authoritative but the lexer should
>   work on a number of languages including C and friends, Java, Python,
>   Bash, SQL, HTML, XML, CSS, Javascript, Makefiles, and Rust.
>
> It works passably on Ruby, PHP, VB, and Awk and a decent subset of
>   Perl and Ruby, but, because of commenting conventions, doesn't work on
>   Smalltalk, OCaml, etc. without a language extension.
>
> Other languages are supported via extensions:
>
> Apollo; Basic; Clojure; CSS; Dart; Erlang; Go; Haskell; Lasso; Lisp,
>   Scheme; Llvm; Logtalk; Lua; Matlab; MLs: F#, Ocaml,SML; Mumps;
>   Nemerle; Pascal; Protocol buffers; R, S; RD; Rust; Scala; SQL; Swift;
>   TCL; Latek; Visual Basic; VHDL; Wiki; XQ; YAML

Comment: This looks great! A sad thing is that internet connection is requred for this. But thanks for this.

Comment: @dixhom I'm not convinced about that. The full source is available on github and you should be able to embed it locally.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is a tricky one. I tried to google myself and only find this library
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2049
which supports different text appearence. Hope this will help you out.